# Get the name of a column and create data from it in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am currently trying to generate new columns [Y, Z] based on the name of another column [X] of the same Dataframe. The problem is that I have not been able to obtain the name of the column and pass it as data to a new column.

I am trying something like this:

```
df['Y'] = df.assign(lambda c: df.columns.values['X'])
df['Z'] = df.apply(lambda c: df.columns.values['X'])
```

As an example, the dataframe would look something like this:

```
>>> df_original
       name  example_col
  0  shakir   33
  1   rafiq   37
  2     dev   36
  3   suraj   30

>>> df_new
       name  new_col        value
  0  shakir   example_col    33
  1   rafiq   example_col    37
  2     dev   example_col    36
  3   suraj   example_col    30
```

But I am not very close to a solution and I've already tried in various ways... :(

Please give me an idea where should I go?

Thank you in advance for your time, I will be attentive to your answers!

Regards!

Comment: Gonza, I would be good if you place an example of your dataframe looks like and the desired output you want, this will bring the right attention on your post.  May be you are looking for something `df['Y'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['X'], axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer as per the edited post:

Example:

```
>>> df
     name  example_col
0  shakir           33
1   rafiq           37
2     dev           36
3   suraj           30
```

### Solution:

you can try using `set_index()` with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and the `rename` the new default formed `columns` `level_1`  & `0` as follows:

```
>>> df.set_index('name').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'new_col', 0:'value'})
     name      new_col  value
0  shakir  example_col     33
1   rafiq  example_col     37
2     dev  example_col     36
3   suraj  example_col     30
```

OR - you can try with [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars=['name'], var_name='new_col')
     name      new_col  value
0  shakir  example_col     33
1   rafiq  example_col     37
2     dev  example_col     36
3   suraj  example_col     30
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and idea, I made the change to explain myself better!

Comment: thank!!, yes it is great since it opens the way for the next thing I need to do, thank you very much !!

Comment: I thank you again, because the function you told me is great! thank you very much friend!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the index of the column you want to copy the name of then:

```py
df_new = df_original.copy()
df_new.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df_new.columns[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris, I am reviewing what you comment, the issue is that I do not need to invert the data of the columns, I need to assign only the name of the column to a new one of the same dataframe, and repeat its value for all records. From already thank you very much!

Comment: @Gonza Can you give an example of input and the output you are aiming for?

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help, yes I just modified my post with a clearer example. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!! yes that was it, finally !! :)
Excuse me Chris !!, I do not have the level to give you points, they are pending for when I have them ;)